# How to print tiff file in java?

Tags: java, printing

I am writing tiff reader library and I want to add print action into it.

Is there anybody who can tell me how to print tiff file with page selection in java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try? What was the result? What didn't work?

Comment: DocPrintJob pj = sps.createPrintJob();

Comment: Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(this, flavor, null);
            
            pj.print(doc, aset);

Comment: I tried code above but it does not show print dialog